# How to combine 2 xml to one with distinct child node using xslt

Tags: xml, xslt

I have requirement to combine 2 xml file into single file with distinct child node in result file. I am able to combine file based on key node but child element value is not coming properly.

Please find below detail.

XML file 1-

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<EF_Candidate_List>
<EF_Candidate>
   <candidate_id>83185</candidate_id>
   <name>test</name>
   <preflocation>USA</preflocation>
</EF_Candidate>
<EF_Candidate>
   <candidate_id>83185</candidate_id>
   <name>test</name>
   <preflocation>IND</preflocation>
</EF_Candidate>
</EF_Candidate_List>
```

XML file 2-

```
<EF_Candidate_list>
<EF_Candidate>
   <candidate_id>83185</candidate_id>
   <JobLevel>1</JobLevel>
   <jobtype>test1</jobtype>
</EF_Candidate>
<EF_Candidate>
   <candidate_id>83185</candidate_id>
   <JobLevel>2</JobLevel>
   <jobtype>test</jobtype>
</EF_Candidate>
<EF_Candidate>
   <candidate_id>83185</candidate_id>
   <JobLevel>3</JobLevel>
   <jobtype>test3</jobtype>
</EF_Candidate>
</EF_Candidate_list>
```

Expected result file

```
<EF_Candidate_List>
<EF_Candidate>
   <candidate_id>83185</candidate_id>
    <name>test</name>
    <preflocation_list>
    <preflocation>IND</preflocation>
    <preflocation>USA</preflocation>
    <preflocation_list>
<profiles>
  <profile>
    <JobLevel>1</JobLevel>
    <jobtype>test1</jobtype>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <JobLevel>2</JobLevel>
    <jobtype>test2</jobtype>
  </profile>
  <profile>
    <JobLevel>3</JobLevel>
  <jobtype>test3</jobtype>
  </profile>
</profiles>
</EF_Candidate_List>
</EF_Candidate>
```

I have following code

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" omit-xml-declaration="yes" indent="yes"/>
<!-- identity transform -->
<xsl:template match="@*|node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@*|node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>
<xsl:template match="EF_Candidate_List">
<EF_Candidate_List xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance">
<xsl:for-each-group select="EF_Candidate" group-by="candidate_id">
<EF_Candidate>

<xsl:variable name="current_candidate_id" select="candidate_id"/>
<xsl:variable name="JobLevel" select="document('file2.xml')/EF_Candidate_List/EF_Candidate[candidate_id = $current_candidate_id]/JobLevel" /> 
<xsl:sequence select="candidate_id" />
<name><xsl:value-of select="name"/></name>
<preflocation_list>
<xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="preflocation">
<preflocation><xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(.)"/></preflocation>
</xsl:for-each-group>
<preflocation_list>
<JobLevel_list>
<xsl:for-each-group select="document('file2.xml')/EF_Candidate_List/EF_Candidate[candidate_id = $current_candidate_id]/JobLevel" group-by="$JobLevel">
<JobLevel><xsl:value-of select="distinct-values(.)"/></JobLevel>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</JobLevel_list>
</EF_Candidate>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</EF_Candidate_List>
</xsl:template>
```

current output

```
<EF_Candidate_List>
<EF_Candidate>
   <candidate_id>83185</candidate_id>
    <name>test</name>
<preflocation_list>
   <preflocation>IND</preflocation>
   <preflocation>USA</preflocation>
   <preflocation_list>
<JobLevels>
    <JobLevel>1</JobLevel>
    <JobLevel>1</JobLevel>
    <JobLevel>1</JobLevel>
</JobLevels>
</EF_Candidate_List>
</EF_Candidate>
```

I am new to xslt hence finding difficulties to trouble shoot. Any help will be much appreciated.

Comment: I have rolled your question back to what it was when I answered it - for the second time!

Answer (score 0):

***--- edited in response to change in question --***

To get the result you show, you can do:

**XSLT 2.0**

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="2.0" 
xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space elements="*"/>

<xsl:key name="cnd" match="EF_Candidate" use="candidate_id" />

<xsl:template match="/EF_Candidate_List">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:for-each-group select="EF_Candidate" group-by="candidate_id">
            <xsl:copy>
                <xsl:copy-of select="candidate_id, name"/>
                <preflocation_list>
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()/preflocation"/>
                </preflocation_list>
                <profiles>
                    <xsl:for-each select="key('cnd', candidate_id, document('file2.xml'))">
                        <profile>
                            <xsl:copy-of select="JobLevel, jobtype"/>
                        </profile>
                    </xsl:for-each> 
                </profiles>
            </xsl:copy>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: My file contain duplicate entries however I am able to resolve issue by below code   
 ''</JobLevel_list>                                                                                                          
 <xsl:for-each-group select="current-group()" group-by="$JobLevel">
<JobLevels>
<JobLevel><xsl:value-of select="current-grouping-key()"/></JobLevel>
</JobLevels>
</xsl:for-each-group>
</JobLevel_list>```

Comment: I am afraid your code makes no sense to me. See the addition to my answer.

Comment: I have edit my question as per you suggested .Seeking assistance from you. Appreciated your time so much.

Comment: I have edited my answer. In the future, please do not make such major changes in your question after it has been answered.

Comment: Thanks a lot for valuable input. I will make sure not to make major changes in future. I used your code in my program but it is giving duplicate record in file. I think it is running for other child element as well in file2.I have again slightly modified file 2 for your reference. Apologies for inconvenience

Comment: Sorry, I will not make any more changes. If you have a different problem, I suggest you post a new question.

Comment: I have posted new question-https://stackoverflow.com/questions/72367229/how-to-combine-2-xml-to-one-with-distinct-child-node-and-sub-element-using-xslt . if you can look it will be great help. Appreciate your time so much